# Derivative of unknown functions and constants

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I'm trying to do symbolic differentiation with Mathematica for expressions with unkown functions and constans.
For example the following expression:

$$\text{expr} = \omega_1 Q_1^2 Q_2 + \frac{Q_1^3}{\sigma Q_2}$$

Where I know that $\sigma$ and $\omega_1$ are constants, but $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ are functions of $t$, I'm trying to find the symbolic time derivative of the expression.

I'm not sure how to tell Mathematica which symbols are constants and which are functions in order to calculate the derivative. Is there a simple way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: `expr=w1*q1[t]^2*q2[t]+q1[t]^3/(s*q2[t]);D[expr,t]`  tells it which are functions of t and lets it find the derivatives for you

Comment: Thank you! That's easy enough

Comment: Note also that if one doesn't want to use `*[t]`, you can instead include the option `NonConstants -> {q1, q2}` in `D`, e.g. `expr=w1*q1^2*q2+q1^3/(s*q2); D[expr, t, NonConstants -> {q1, q2}]`. this is useful for defining these derivatives to have fixed values by upvalues, but otherwise the output is less than pretty, so using `*[t]` if possible is preferable imo—just thought I'd mention :)